# User-defined message not working

Tags: multithreading, winapi

Brief summary of what i am trying to accomplish - I am 'attempting' to write code that will allow an operator to test 4 devices simultaneously using winapi threads. The code for the testing of the units works fine, the threading works. Within a thread i would like to send either pass or fail message to a listbox on the main window (hwnd). Here is some code...

```
#define WM_TEST_RESULT (WM_USER+1)

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
int wmId, wmEvent;
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
HDC hdc;
static INT i;
RECT rect;

switch (message)
{
// This never gets called while running
case WM_TEST_RESULT:
    i = lParam;
    if(test1[i].passed == true)
        SendDlgItemMessage(hwnd,IDT_RESULTLIST1,LB_ADDSTRING,i,(LPARAM)"PASS");
    else SendDlgItemMessage(hwnd,IDT_RESULTLIST1,LB_ADDSTRING,i,(LPARAM)"FAIL");
    MessageBox(hwnd,"test",0,0); //debug
break;
case WM_CREATE:
    hText14 = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,WC_LISTBOX,0,WS_VISIBLE|WS_TABSTOP|WS_CHILD,
                165,185,40,325,hwnd,(HMENU)IDT_RESULTLIST1,hInst,FALSE);
break;
case WM_COMMAND:
    wmId    = LOWORD(wParam);
    wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);

    switch(LOWORD(wParam))
    {
        case IDB_STARTBUTTON1:

        break;
        case IDB_STARTBUTTON2:

        break;
        case IDB_STARTBUTTON3:

        break;
        case IDB_STARTBUTTON4:

        break;
        case IDB_RUNTESTBUTTON1:
            _beginthread(Thread1,0,NULL);
            break;
        case IDB_RUNTESTBUTTON2:
            _beginthread(Thread2,0,NULL);
            break;
        case IDB_RUNTESTBUTTON3:
            _beginthread(Thread3,0,NULL);
            break;
        case IDB_RUNTESTBUTTON4:
            _beginthread(Thread4,0,NULL);
            break;
    }   
    // Parse the menu selections:
    switch (wmId)
    {
    //case IDM_ABOUT:
        //DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hwnd, About);
    //  break;
    case IDD_PROPPAGE_MEDIUM:
        DialogBox(GetModuleHandle(NULL),MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_PROPPAGE_MEDIUM), hwnd, Config);
        break;
    case IDM_EXIT:
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    break;
case WM_PAINT:
    hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    // TODO: Add any drawing code here...
    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    break;
case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;
default:
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
return 0;
}
```

Here is the calling thread...

```
void Thread1(PVOID pvoid)
{
for(int i=0;i<numberOfTests1;i++) {     
    int ret;
    double TimeOut = 60.0;
    int Lng = 1;
    test1[i].testNumber = getTestNumber(test1[i].testName);
    //test1[i].testNumber = CMD_TOOL_BUZZER; //debug only
    unsigned char Param[255] = {0};
    unsigned char Port1 = port1;

    ret = PSB30_Open(Port1, 16);
    ret = PSB30_SendOrder (Port1, test1[i].testNumber, &Param[0], &Lng, &TimeOut); 
    ret = PSB30_Close (Port1);
    int result = 0;

    if(*Param == 1) {
        test1[i].passed = true;
        SendMessage(hwnd,WM_TEST_RESULT,i,(LPARAM)"PASS");
    }else {
        test1[i].passed = false;
        SendMessage(hwnd,WM_TEST_RESULT,i,(LPARAM)"FAIL");
    }   
}
_endthread();
}
```

I have looked at other source code and cant see anything different to what i am trying to accomplish, does anyone have any ideas? If required i can add more source code, but i think somewere in this code is were the issue(s) are.

Cheers

Comment: 1.) _endthread() shouldn't be necessary. 2.) Is hwnd in your Thread1 function the correct window? 3.) When you set a breakpoint at the SendMessage calls, do you ever get there?

Comment: 2. This is the handle to my main window the listbox is attached to this. 3. I get to the sendmessage using  breakpoint, but it doesn't do anything, it returns 0 when i debug

Comment: SendMessage returns the return value from the WindowProc, so 0 is not an error since you do a `return 0;`. You could use Spy++ (included in VC++) to check the message queues of your windows.

Comment: hmmm, tried to run a couple of times and i am getting the following error message - Spy++ has encountered a problem with the message hook

Comment: One thing I just noticed is that you do `i = lParam;`. lParam is the address of the string parameter. In the SendMessage function you pass i as wParam.

Comment: changed the lparam to wparam but still nothing, restarted pc and ran spy++, getting nothing regarding WM_TEST_RESULT displayed, so not really sure whats wrong

Comment: You have not shown enough code to really diagnose this, but if `SendMessage()` is not triggering `WndProc()` then the thread's `hwnd` variable not actually pointing to the window you think it is.

Comment: is there anyway to determine the correct window i should be pointing to, sorry if this sounds a bit lame, but i am relatively new to windows programming

Comment: @Remy also i should have mentioned this but when i put the user-defined message inside `WM_COMMAND` it does populate the listbox, obviously in the wrong place but shows that the `hwnd` is either correct or something in `WndProc()` is causing it to change?

Comment: @Remy, managed to fix this, seems like i had an extra HWND hwnd, within my code that was overwriting my global hwnd, many thnaks for all your help

Answer (score 0):

WM_USER messages are reserved for window class authors, it is better to use WM_APP + xxx for application private messages. It your window is a dialog, for example, WM_USER + 1 should not work as expected. See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/10/24/10362204.aspx) for detalied explanation.